# Is it good practice to return available Options for the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a new api and i'm trying to decide if it would be a good practice to include the list of available options as well as the selected option when returning an entity back from the database.

Take for example

```
class car
{
   int Id;
   Type Type;
   List<Type> Types;
}

class Type
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

I've seen this done both ways, so I was wondering if there was a preference.

Thanks

Comment: Normally I would expect any API to have some kind of documentation in which possible options are enumerated and described.  Just fetching a record wouldn't usually return this information.  You *could* have another API endpoint for the sole purpose of returning lists of options.

Comment: make additional methods to get at the additional metadata someone may need. don't give people 'extra' stuff unless there is a definitive need. otherwise you're just bulking up responses for no good reason other than 'some people may or may not want this'

Comment: What do you mean by "the list of available options", exactly? What does that code have to do with it? What is an "option"?

Comment: Agreed. Keep additional data (like possible options) out of responses to general request. There should be a seperate way to get this kind of documentation information (Documentation, Shema, seperate Function). As for the used options: I would err on not returning that. Most likely a querry to this API will be done via Multitasking/Multithreading so the caller will still have the request he send right there. Just keep in mind to be agressive with Input validaiton and input error reporting, especially on options and with string inputs via a network.

Comment: Along the lines of generating the documentation everyone has been talking about take a look at the NuGet package [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/) this library is the one microsoft uses in it's default template if you choose to make a new Azure API project.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is wrong, let's see with an example:

We have two car objects `car1` and `car2`, and the types are `type1`, `type2`, `type3`. The result object when you query the car list is:

- `{car1, type1, {type1,type2,type3}}`
- `{car2, type2, {type1,type2,type3}}`

Can you see the redundancy on returning the same list twice? There's your design mistake.

You only have to pass the type's list if it's really necessary or else you'll be sending duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it would not be a good design to return a list of car types. Considering car as an entity, the car will be of a certain type. And of course, there would be redundancy for little value as @DiegoS mentioned.

You may have a separate API for returning all the valid types for a car if needed.